# Vim with incorrect colors - Konsole and Yakuake

Tags: linux, vim

I'am using vim in Konsole and Yakuake. But I can't see the correct colorscheme.

My .vimrc file have the following text:

```
t_Co=256
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme desert
```

My OS is Debian Sid.

Can you help me?

Comment: did you forget the set in `set t_Co=256` and what is the output of `:colorscheme`

Comment: What is your `$TERM` environment variable? It needs to be a 256 color environment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832660/why-dont-most-vim-color-schemes-look-as-nice-as-the-screenshot-when-i-use-them/9833425#9833425

Comment: Same problem with "set t_Co=256".

Comment: My $TERM environment is: "TERM=xterm-256color".

Comment: What do you have (screenshot) and what do you expect (screenshot)? Also, the 1st and 3rd line are not needed.

Comment: Have you tried [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390)? It solved console color issues for me.

Comment: My Screenshot: http://es.zimagez.com/zimage/sinnombre5.php

You Should see:

http://es.zimagez.com/zimage/sinnombre20.php

Comment: do you mean effect of `colorscheme desert` is NOT correct?

Comment: My colorscheme should be: http://es.zimagez.com/zimage/sinnombre20.php but now my colorscheme is: http://es.zimagez.com/zimage/sinnombre5.php I can't see the correct colors.

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems to be Konsole/Yakuake issue. On gnome-terminal, or xterm in AwesomeWM colors work correctly for me.

Answer (score 2):

you need [csapprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) plugin to correctly display some color schemes in terminal