# Vim line number setting not showing when using tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

When I use vim (set number)  in the .vimrc file, it works fine in the terminal, but when using tmux the line numbers just don't show.

Comment: Are the numbers present, but in a color that doesn't show up? If you highlight your terminal text under tmux, can you see the line numbers highlighted? If you do `set nu` and `set nonu` can you see the buffer text shift over to accommodate the line numbers (that is, do they take up space)?

Comment: Yes the do take space and the text does shift :( they are there but I just cant see them

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and the .vimrc are from https://github.com/chrishunt/dot-files/blob/master/.vimrc mostly and the .tmux.conf are also mostly form https://github.com/chrishunt/dot-files/blob/master/.tmux.conf I just took off the zsh part for I'm using bash

Comment: Try a different simpler colorscheme: `colorscheme desert`.  Your tmux.conf sets `screen-256color` as the term type, but what does `echo $TERM` actually give you in tmux vs a plain terminal?

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832660/why-dont-most-vim-color-schemes-look-as-nice-as-the-screenshot-when-i-use-them/9833425#9833425) and try setting `t_Co` in your regular colorscheme if changing the colorscheme helps

Comment: As for term when echo $TERM it gives back xterm as for tmux it gives back screen-256color

Comment: Ok it is the colorscheme but it is working fine with a different one kolor but it can't be this is  Base16 every one is using it why this is happening to me :(any way thanks man and desert seem great might as will try it

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the same `$TERM` for your shell and tmux. Otherwise this will cause all kinds of trouble, especially when used in connection with powerline (or vim in your case).

See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux#Setting_the_correct_term

Answer (score 2):

As answered by [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23275974/765960), you have to actually set the correct `$TERM` for **BOTH** your shell and **TMUX**

I also had a similar problem like yours today and got it working with the following steps.

To know your current $TERM in your shell, you can use the command:

```
echo $TERM
```

for me, I got the output `xterm-256color`.

Then in your `~/.tmux.conf` file, you can set the tmux to use `xterm-256color` by adding this to the file.

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

and all should work fine. :)

Hope I've helped.